# What's the correct form of the word "size" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

What's the correct form of the word "size" in this sentence?

> Do you have these shirts in large size?

or

> Do you have these shirts in large size**s**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would depend on whether you're asking for a specific size (large), or if you're asking about the several sizes that are considered large (large, extra large, extra extra large, etc).

> "Do you have these shirts in large size?"

This sentence indicates that you're asking for shirts in **the** size known as Large. In which case, it'd be better to remove *size*, as it is clearly understood regardless, or perhaps by saying "*the* large size."

> "Do you have these shirts in large sizes?"

There is nothing wrong with this sentence grammatically, though perhaps saying "*the* large sizes" might clarify things a bit. Like I said before, this is implying that you're looking for multiple sizes. If you want **the** large size, then you'd be better off with the first example, modified as specified.

Comment: in large size is not right in English.

Comment: Then we are in agreement, no?

Answer (score 2):

In American English, a more natural way to ask this question is:

> Do you have this shirt in (a) large?

The "a" is optional.

Comment: Yes, in (a) large (size) is what it was before.

Comment: It's just as likely that it's an elision of "Do you have this shirt in a (size) large," the same way we might ask "Do you have this shirt in a (size) two" or "Do you have these shoes in a (size) ten"